# How to get folder name thats different on all user profiles

Tags: powershell, variables, appdata

I like to know how to get `5J91Q4CX.C10` to use in a variable.

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\5J91Q4CX.C10
```

On all user profiles this folder has a different name. 
It is always 8 numbers and digits then a `.` and then 3 digits or numbers.

I need to use this for a powershell script.

Any idea how I can make a variable for this foldername?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
#Loop through all user profile folders using something like this:
$userFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\" -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
                Where-Object { @('All Users','Default User', 'Public', 'Default') -notcontains $_.Name } |
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

# next loop through these folders to find the foldername that can be different for each user
foreach ($userName in $userFolders) {
    $folderName = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\$userName\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0" -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
                    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '[A-Za-z0-9]{8}\.[A-Za-z0-9]{3}' } |
                    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    # do something with this variable
   Write-Host "C:\Users\$userName\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\$folderName"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some `RegEx` could do the trick:

```
$str = "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\5J91Q4CX.C10"
$str -match '.*\\(.*)$'

$matches[1] # 5J91Q4CX.C10
```

`.*\\(.*)$` matches all chars after the last dash `\` and before the end of the line `$`

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you are really trying to do... you could do a directory search through the C:\Users to report back on all subfolders and then a Foreach loop to go through each subfolder and create the file wanted in the destination etc, something like:

```
$FOLDERS = Get-ChildItem C:\Users -Directory

FOREACH ($FOLDER in $FOLDERS) {
#WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO
}
```